# Hibernate insert causes update of another table

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a model that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
class A {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "A_categories", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "A_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id",
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<Category> categories;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
class Category {
     @Id
     @Column(name="id")
     @GeneratedValue
     private Integer id;

     @Column(name = "category_name")
     private String categoryName;

     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "categories")
     private List<A> a;

}
```

So there is a many-to-many relationship between `A` and `Category`.  Now categories are static, and cannot be changed by a user.  From the UI, the user will try to save an entity `A`, and each can have one or more categories.  So the JSON that comes back looks a little like this:

```
{A: {categories: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]}}
```

Now when I try to save this `A` object (after jackson has unmarshalled to java), I just want entries to be made in the join table, `A_categories`, for each category the new entity has.

However, the `Category` entity itself also gets updated.  So if you notice, the JSON does not have any `category_name`, and so the database entry for each `Category` will also get updated to a `null` entry for the name.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different approaches:

1) **Set managed categories before merging.**

```
a.setCategories(readAllByIds(a.getCategories()))

private Collection<Category> readAllByIds(Collection<Category> categories) {
  Collection<Category> result = new ArrayList();
  for (Category category : categories) {
    result.add(entityManager.getReference(Category.class, category.getId()));
  }
  return result;
}
```

[`EntityManager.getReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-) returns proxy, so the additional benefit is that no database round trips are executed for reading the associated categories.

With this solution you are not merging the deserialized categories into the persistence context, thus Hibernate will not synchronize their state with the database.

2) **Do not cascade any operations from `A` to `categories`** (remove `cascade` attribute).

This way, neither `PERSIST` nor `MERGE` will be cascaded and Hibernate will just use ids of the detached `Category` instances to store the data into the relationship table.

Sidenote: Generally, cascading `REMOVE` or `ALL` in a many-to-many association makes no sense (if you remove an `A` you probably don't want to remove all the categories it belongs to).

Comment: The second solution did it.  It makes perfect sense to remove it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Column has the attributes insertable and updatable. You can set them to false:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
class Category {
     @Id
     @Column(name="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
     @GeneratedValue
     private Integer id;

     @Column(name = "category_name", insertable=false, updatable=false)
     private String categoryName;

     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "categories")
     private List<A> a;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
class Category {
 @Id
 @Column(name="id")
 @GeneratedValue
 private Integer id;

 @Column(name = "category_name")
 private String categoryName;

 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "categories", cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
 private List<A> a;
```

}

with the cascade.DETACH should not save changes when you save A entity, but let me know if is not working to make an example modifying the ManyToMany relationship with this DETACH action